# Linux Script which show name of all loged in students and the number of their simulatos number login

Tags: linux, bash

It works good but, i want to print lines uniqly and the number of how many times the line is repeated.

```
#!/bin/bash

who |grep "10\.1\.109" | grep -v berianho | cut -f1 -d " " | sort -n|

while read user 
do 
    grep -a ^$user: /etc/passwd | cut -f5 -d:
done
```

Comment: Anyone can help me with this? Printing all lines uniqely and count them how many times are repeated?

Comment: `... done | sort | uniq -c` is worth trying. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For newcomers to the Unix/Linux command line, it is almost impossible to grasp the wealth and ease of the simple commands that are available. And, although it is easy to refer to the manual, that will probably not help in finding the specific section.

But you should look at the manual, in your case `man uniq`. And look at the `-c` specifically.

So, `who | cut -f1 -d " " | sort -n` (I omitted the `grep`s, because they do mean anything on my system) produces:

and `who | cut -f1 -d " " | sort -n | uniq -c` produces:

```
   1 anneke
   2 ljm
   1 root
```

which is exactly what you asked.

Your while loop should probably read the line count, like in

```
who |
  grep "10\.1\.109" | 
  grep -v berianho  | 
  cut -f1 -d " "    |
  sort -n           |
  uniq -c           |
  while read count user ; do
    echo -n "$count "
    grep -a ^$user: /etc/passwd | cut -f5 -d:
done
```

or something like that. It is important to see that you now read two variables, count and user, from each line of the output of `uniq`.

Comment: I tried adding |uniq -c| after sort command but again its not working.

Comment: I didn't understand this. Could you please edit my code in the right way?